# How to update data in nested MongoDB object by mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this user model schema in my MongoDB database:

```
{
    "fullname":  "my name",
     "topics":  [
        {
            "name": "city",         
            "data": null,
            "subset":[ 
                {
                    "name": "tempreture",
                    "data": null,
                    "subset": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "contamination",
                    "data": null,
                    "subset": null
               }
           ]
        }]
    }
```

I need a solution by mongoose to update the **data** where **name: "contamination"** from a URL like this: **myname/city/contamination**.

EDIT:
This is my user model (user.js):

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose');
  var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

  var userSchema = Schema({
  fullname: String,
    email: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    active: Boolean,
    activator: String,
    topics: [{ type: Object, ref: 'Topic' }],
    clients: [{ type: Object, ref: 'Client' }]
  });

  var topicSchema = Schema({
    name   : String,
    data     : Array,
    subset : [{ type: Object, ref: 'Topic' }]
  });

  var clientSchema = Schema({
    name       : String,
    password   : String,
    permissions : [{ type: Object, ref: 'Permission' }]
  });

  var permissionSchema = Schema({
    topic : String,
    read  : Boolean,
    write : Boolean
  });

  var Permission  = mongoose.model('Permission', permissionSchema);
  var Client  = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);
  var Topic  = mongoose.model('Topic', topicSchema);

  module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: Can you show your UserSchema ? with the fields and their DataTypes.

Comment: @RaviShankar yes, I added my whole user.js (my user schema)

Comment: are you able to fetch myname, city and contamination from the URL?

Comment: How is `User` saved in your `Mongo DB`? is `topics` an array of `ObjectID`'s?

Comment: Actually I did not add my user by this schema I added this directly from Rockmongo.

Comment: Actually, according to your `UserSchema`, `User` will contain `array` of `ObjectId` in `topic` and `client` field. Similarly, fields which have `ref` to another `collection`, will have `ObjectId` in its place.

Comment: oops! my mistake. I don't want `ObjectId` , I changed `UserSchema`; but this is not my problem for now. I added this user directly from Rockmongo and I need to know how to get `contamination` data